# Ansible : Multiple loops in a playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with following content

```
---
# Play 1 : Create Networks
- name: create networks based on options in Database_vars.json
  hosts: target
  tasks:
    - include_vars: "Database_vars.json"
      tags: [always]

    - name: Create Networks(s)
      include_tasks:
        file: createNetworkSub.yaml
        apply:
          tags:
            - createNetwork
      loop: "{{ createNetwork }}"
      tags: [createNetwork,never]
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Database_vars.json looks like this

```
{
  "createNetwork": [
        {
            "id": "abc",
            "name": "Public-network",
        },
        {
            "id": "xyz",
            "name": "Private-network",
        }
   ]
}
```

Now I have another json machines.json like this.

```
{
  "oda8m032": {
    "nodename": ["oda8m032"],
    "networks": {
                 "abc" : ["net1", "10.1.2.3"],
                 "xyz" : ["net4", "10.1.2.4"],
                 "akash_net2" : ["net3", "10.1.2.5"],
                 "akash_net3" : ["net4", "10.1.2,6"]
                }
  }
}
```

I need to loop over the list of networks from Database_vars.json and create the ones which are there in machines.json for that host (oda8m032 in this example). Can anyone please help with this double looping here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
oda8m032
oda8m033
```

The included tasks

```yaml
shell> cat createNetworkSub.yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      id: {{ item.id }}
      networks: {{ node.networks[item.id] }}
  when: node
  vars:
    node: "{{ lookup('vars', inventory_hostname, default={}) }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t createNetwork

  ...

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [oda8m033]
ok: [oda8m032] => 
  msg: |-
    id: abc
    networks: ['net1', '10.1.2.3']

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [oda8m032] => 
  msg: |-
    id: xyz
    networks: ['net4', '10.1.2.4']
skipping: [oda8m033]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    createNetwork:
      - id: abc
        name: Public-network
      - id: xyz
        name: Private-network

    oda8m032:
      networks:
        abc: [net1, 10.1.2.3]
        akash_net2: [net3, 10.1.2.5]
        akash_net3: [net4, '10.1.2,6']
        xyz: [net4, 10.1.2.4]
      nodename: [oda8m032]

  tasks:

    - include_tasks:
        file: createNetworkSub.yaml
        apply:
          tags: createNetwork
      loop: "{{ createNetwork }}"
      tags: [createNetwork, never]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Vladimir. My vars variable just has Database_vars.json. So, on lookup it won't find oda8m032 which is part of machines.json. Any suggestions here ?